# fs.createReadStream only reading last line of file node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, stream, fs

Hi I'm trying to simply stream the contents of my csv file and I'm having some really annoying issues. Bellow is my code and my frustrations are tucked inside my comments.

```
var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(inFile);

// For some reason readable will yield only the last line of my file
// and if I listen for 'data' I still just get the last line of my file
fileReadStream.on('readable', function() {
  process.stdout.write(fileReadStream.read().toString());
}).on('end', function() {
  i ++;
  next();
});
```

Any help on this would be great. Also I'm very confused on how to make something pipe correctly. From my interpretation, I feel like with piped objects, pipe will simply write to the object inside the pipe and then call read on that object. But I haven't been able to get pipe to work that well. Maybe when I solve this problem, I can figure out pipe easier. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that it is loading the entire file into the buffer and you are only seeing the last line when it is output?  Add an on error piece to make sure it is not throwing errors.  Also, you may want to look at using a csv library to work with csv files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply do something like:

```
var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(inFile);
fileReadStream.on('end', function() {
  i++;
  next();
}).pipe(process.stdout);
```